# Issues Connecting to Local SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have been trying to connect to a local SQL Server that I have created via Excel VBA but I am having issues.

I am able to connect to the database using the "Get Data" functionality within Excel and entering in the server as `(Local DB)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

However when I try connecting using VBA it does not work, using Windows authentication. Any ideas?

Here is the string I used:

```
strConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

The error I get is

> Run-time error '2147467259 (80004005)'
>
> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]
>
> SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it, test it.    TEST is Database name.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" _
         & "Server=(local);" _
         & "Database=TEST;" _
         & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
         & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     ' Carl SQL Server Connection
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "Your_Server_Name" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "NORTHWND" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [Customers]" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```